# How to pass Form value from one function to other function and display

Tags: javascript

I have three file index.html,success.html and index.js
and I want to validate form than redirect accordingly and prind form data on success page? anable to access variable from one function to other
As code my code here from

```js
function check() {
  x = document.forms.myform.fname.value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("First Name should be filled out!");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Login Successful");
    window.location.href = "success.html";
    return false;
  }
}
// onload name function from success.html
function name() {
  document.getElementById('fn').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Form Validation</h1>
  <form method="post" action="success.html" name="myform" onsubmit="return(check())">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

success.html

```js
function check() {
  x = document.forms.myform.fname.value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("First Name should be filled out!");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Login Successful");
    window.location.href = "success.html";
    return false;
  }
}
// onload name function from success.html
function name() {
  document.getElementById('fn').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="./index.js"></script> 
</head>
<body onload="name()">
  <h1>Your form is submitted successfull.</h1>
  <p>Thanks</p>
  <div id="fn">Name Here</div>
  <hr width="50%">
</body>
```

Comment: your window.location.href is reloading everything so its all gone. Ideally serve the success window in a modal. this will keep all js variables in play. Otherwise you could utilize localstorage to save the form off and load with success.html (but this is a distant second choice)

Comment: `document.getElementById('fn').innerHTML = x;` will not work across pages

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that without having a server side component is to utilize GET instead of POST in your form. Also, take away the window.location line - you want the form to submit naturally

```
function check() {
    if (document.forms.myform.fname.value == "") {
        alert("First Name should be filled out!");
        return false;
    } 
   return true;
}

<form method="get" action="success.html" name="myform" onsubmit="return(check())">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

And on the receiving page access the page URL with `window.location.href`...

```js
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/success.html?fname=John"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("fname");
console.log(c);
```

Comment: What if multiple page for redirection based on  used input  and  multi-level validation